# SSIS PACKAGE_ How to update data in more than two table using single SSIS Package

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I want to update three tables from CSV File in a single SSIS package.
I am done with updating the single table by comparing CSV file and table, I have attach the screenshot its working fine. But when I trying to update more than 3 tables in single package getting the problem in updating records.

[image]

so please share the detailed steps to update multiple(more than two) tables

Comment: Use UNION with your 3 source before doing the merge join with the table.

Comment: Which third table do you want to update and why? You could add a third condition to your conditional split and point the output to a third destination?

Comment: Why cant you get data into a staging table and perform look up or use Merge script for updating the table which supports best practices

Comment: Not enough information. What tables are you trying to update? What is the command to Update? What is the error? Or, do you now knot how to do this and asking us to do it for you? Note if the latter, we are not here for that - we are here to fix specific problems.

Comment: Problem is solved.... I created 3 different data flows for each table

Answer (score 0):

Please be clear about how you want to update more than three tables?
or on basis of conditions, you want to insert and update data?